# why signalR heartbeat no client response required

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

SouceCode: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/72418317c95182fd8d2f8ba1b69b02bfbb79baaa/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Transports/TransportHeartBeat.cs

The server sends a heartbeat packet and then marks the connection alive without waiting for the client to respond

```
    private void CheckTimeoutAndKeepAlive(ConnectionMetadata metadata)
    {
        if (RaiseTimeout(metadata))
        {
            // If we're past the expiration time then just timeout the connection
            metadata.Connection.Timeout();
        }
        else
        {
            // The connection is still alive so we need to keep it alive with a server side "ping".
            // This is for scenarios where networking hardware (proxies, loadbalancers) get in the way
            // of us handling timeout's or disconnects gracefully
            if (RaiseKeepAlive(metadata))
            {
                Trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, "KeepAlive(" + metadata.Connection.ConnectionId + ")");

                // Ensure delegate continues to use the C# Compiler static delegate caching optimization.
                metadata.Connection.KeepAlive().Catch((ex, state) => OnKeepAliveError(ex, state), state: Trace, traceSource: Trace);
            }

            MarkConnection(metadata.Connection);
        }
    }
```

How to detect that the client has been disconnected？
How the client detects itself and the server is disconnected？

Comment: Share your code here and give us more details abut your question

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on your connection type. (Socket, LongPolling etc.) Sockets gives you a TCP/UDP port connection and it gives you the disconnected notification.

For other type of connections, heartbeat or other things work. SignalR core uses heartbeat with one second interval. So, SignalR Core detects the disconnect in one second.